How Does One Use a Pre-Trained Voice Model Using So-Vits-Svc-Fork 4.2.3 Singing Voice Conversion Algorithm?
I am looking to start a few "AI voice cover" projects utilizing the so-vits-svc-fork program I had installed from Github.
I have the program up and running through Anaconda as Python is the language this program uses.
There are torturials on how to build and train your own voice data sets using the program. Where my problem comes in is that I have a pretrained voice model downloaded that I want to use, but simply selecting the model plus the vocals I want the program to convert will only spit back out an error multiple times before giving up as shown below:so-vits-svc-fork prompt displaying errors after failed execution
I suspect that I lack the "config.json" file for this to work. Do I need to retrain this model to obtain the .json file or does the file already exist as something that could be universally used and located somewhere I am missing. Unfortunately, the directions found on Github aren't exactly "user-friendly". I also have a screenshot of the GUI that I am working with; you can see the files that I am trying to use but I am lacking the "config path": Latest version of the so-vits-svc-fork GUI

I have tried seeing if the .zip file that the model came in had a .json file.
I have tried searching for the "config.json" file extensively in the programs folders to no avail, although there is mention that the default location for "config.json" is "configs/44k/config.json"

I have the link to the Github that includes the directions: https://github.com/voicepaw/so-vits-svc-fork
I really am clueless how little to how big of a problem I have run into. Any pointers are much appericated because I would hate to abandon this program so soon! Thank you!
